# XSLT transformation needed to add a SOAP envelope and split the XML between SOAP header and body

Tags: xslt, soap

I have tried several options suggested in various blogs but would like to know if the following transformation is possible.

I need to convert the following XML,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns1:ReturnLicensesForHost xmlns:ns1="http://example.com">
  <ns1:userName>ABCDEFGH</ns1:userName>
  <ns1:password>1234567</ns1:password>
  <ns1:hostIdType>XYZ</ns1:hostIdType>
  <ns1:hostId>987654</ns1:hostId>
  <ns1:product>STUV</ns1:product>
</ns1:ReturnLicensesForHost>
```

into

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:fs="http://example.com">
   <soap:Header>
      <fs:Credentials>
         <fs:userName>ABCDEFGH</fs:userName>
         <fs:password>1234567</fs:password>
      </fs:Credentials>
   </soap:Header>
   <soap:Body>
      <fs:ReturnLicensesForHost>
         <fs:hostIdType>XYZ</fs:hostIdType>
         <fs:hostId>987654</fs:hostId>
         <fs:product>STUV</fs:product>
      </fs:ReturnLicensesForHost>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

So basically, I need to add a SOAP envelope and split the fields across Header and Body.
Request your help with an XSLT for this transformation.

Comment: I tried to go through certain blogs to add the soap header. There is 1 blog which gives insights to add variables in XML tags to the SOAP header but I need for xml fields

Comment: Have you had a look at [SO QnA](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bxslt%5D+soap)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conversion simply consists of putting the result XML in a template and replacing the desired values with `xsl:value-of` phrases referring to the input XML (including management of namespaces):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns1="http://example.com"> 
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />    

  <xsl:template match="/ns1:ReturnLicensesForHost">
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:fs="http://example.com">
        <soap:Header>
            <fs:Credentials>
                <fs:userName><xsl:value-of select="ns1:userName" /></fs:userName>
                <fs:password><xsl:value-of select="ns1:password" /></fs:password>
            </fs:Credentials>
        </soap:Header>
        <soap:Body>
            <fs:ReturnLicensesForHost>
                <fs:hostIdType><xsl:value-of select="ns1:hostIdType" /></fs:hostIdType>
                <fs:hostId><xsl:value-of select="ns1:hostId" /></fs:hostId>
                <fs:product><xsl:value-of select="ns1:product" /></fs:product>
            </fs:ReturnLicensesForHost>
        </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>   
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:fs="http://example.com" xmlns:ns1="http://example.com">
    <soap:Header>
        <fs:Credentials>
            <fs:userName>ABCDEFGH</fs:userName>
            <fs:password>1234567</fs:password>
        </fs:Credentials>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <fs:ReturnLicensesForHost>
            <fs:hostIdType>XYZ</fs:hostIdType>
            <fs:hostId>987654</fs:hostId>
            <fs:product>STUV</fs:product>
        </fs:ReturnLicensesForHost>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: I tried a similar approach. But I get the output as
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>ABCDEFGH1234567XYZ987654STUV

I am not able to get the SOAP envelope

Pls. ignore. I had to use the actual URL for namespace and now I get the soap envelope.

Comment: What is the value of your `<xsl:output method="..." />`? If it's `text` then you would get this long string, but if it's `xml` you should get the whole output. I accordingly changed my answer.